# How do I make .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 install quietly?

Tags: .net, installation, windows-installer

I am trying to install, as part of my chained bootstrapper installation project, .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. But, when you run the installer, even by itself, with `/q /norestart`, it is anything but quiet. I would expect no user interface, yet I get presented with the following:

[image]

Is there any way to actually make it quiet? I've looked at other threads on Stack and elsewhere, and they all seem to imply that this would be the way to make the installation take place quietly, yet it doesn't.

**Edit**: I know, in the command prompt screenshot I used `\`, but even with `/`, same thing.

Comment: @Mihai Unless...I have the wrong version of the installer... http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=25150

Comment: I think those option are available,or more precisely are used for packages with the .msi extension. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx Exactly,windows installer 3.0+ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372842(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Mihai Microsoft does have some articles about quiet installations being supported for this particular executable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc160716.aspx

Comment: I don`t know what to tell you,maybe try the msi and see if it`s the same thing http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=65

Comment: Note: Just tried both the full or partial .NET 3.5 SP1 package, /quiet is not supported in either redistribute (full or not)

Comment: Try it here also http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Mihai Buna idee :) http://superuser.com/questions/818458/how-do-i-make-net-framework-3-5-sp1-install-quietly

Comment: Heh,salut!Sper ca o sa-ti rezolvi problema.

Comment: @Mihai Looks like in Windows 8 it requires people to use DISM: *DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All*

Comment: Mersi de info,e bine de stiut.

Comment: I think it also automatically installs the latest SP level for that framework version as well, with that command. Just checked the registry for the SP value under *HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5* and it is set to 1.